# local this variable is retaining old value even after clearing

Tags: javascript, reference, scope, this

I am facing a weird issue with "this". I have the code as follow which is for a page. In this I am creating a page and binding the onclick events. Here I reset the self[key] everytime I call funcOne but onClick I am setting the data.

The second time when I call funcOne and again I call onClick the data in this[key] is the old data instead of resetting.

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong here. I am new to Javascript.

```
classExample = function(page) {
    someBaseClass.call(this, page);
}

classExample.prototype.funcOne = function() {
    var self = this;
    var callback = function(data) {
        self[key] = []; //based on some logic I am setting
    };

    model.getData(callback);

    someButton.onClick = function() {
        self.funcTwo();
    };
};

classExample.prototype.funcTwo = function() {
    //function from other class is called and data to this[key] is set
    classTwo.someMethod(this);

    var savedData = this[key];
};

var obj = new classExample(page);
obj.funcOne();
//after this I invoke onClick event
```

PS : I am not using any third party library.

Comment: What is the value of `key` when `funcTwo` is defined compared to when `funcOne` runs (and `callback` is defined)?

Comment: key is same in funcOne and funcTwo. I am using key to store data when I move to other page onclick event. Yes callback is defined.

Comment: When you say you're resetting it in `funcTwo`, what do you mean? It looks like you're just assigning the value at `this[key]` to some local variable.

Comment: @MikeC My bad I forgot to mention this. I have edited the code in funcTwo. I am passing "this" as parameter and setting the value to this[key] which I need in this class.

Comment: @abbie Again, you're just assigning the value to `savedData` which is erased once the function is complete. If you want to "reset" a value then do something like `this[key] = undefined`. The heart of your problem is you're expecting some value to be reset but it isn't. So far I don't see any code which should reset a value.

Comment: Let me tell you the flow. I create the object obj of classExample and then call obj.funcOne(), which creates this[key] as empty array. Then I invoke onClick() which goes to funcTwo and inside funcTwo I call another class method to set some value to this[key] and here after saving this[key] in savedData, I can't reset as I need it later. Now when I do the same thing again as per flow in funcOne this[key] should reset to [] but its giving me the value which I stored from funcTwo.

I have resolved it using a global variable to keep "this" and its working fine but may not be correct way.